# Exporting all the items from FLA file opened in Adobe Animate

Tags: flash, adobe-animate, fla

Since Flash is gone, I am using **Adobe Animate** to open old **fla files**. Is there any easy way to export all the items (including vectors, sounds and images) present in library directly so they can be reused.

Comment: Try JPEXS decompiler if using Windows. It can do batch exporting of items.

Comment: @VC.One From FLA, not from SWF.

Comment: Yep, I don't want to extract assets from a SWF file. It has only the assets that were used in that particular animation. What I want is to get the library items from the FLA files that aren't even used, but present in the fla file.

Comment: @HashirTihami Research **JSFL**. It is an automation script (fairly similar to AS in syntax) that is designed to command the Flash IDE to do anything you can do there with the mouse and keyboard. Like, select/deselect stage objects and Library items, copy/paste/delete, move, edit properties, and so on, and so on. You can start with https://github.com/adoontheway/jsfl-examples/blob/master/exportImagesFromFla.jsfl I googled with "*jsfl examples*" search (look it up as well).

Comment: @HashirTihami Thanks for the clarification. See if my Answer helps you.